# Calculating The Origin of UIButton Directly from the Self.view in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, frame, subviews

My objects' hierarchy is as follows,

[image]

Let's say the UIButton's object name is 'myButton'.
Now, Is there any way to **Calculate the origin(X Coordinate,Y Coordinate) of 'myButton' directly from self.view not by using any intermediate objects' frames**?

Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for UIView

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view;
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point fromView:(UIView *)view;

CGPoint pt = [button converPoint:button.bound.origin toView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

u can try this

```
 CGRect frame =  [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:self.view];
```

frame contains origin information relative to self.view